# Css and Bootstrap in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a project and am using Twitter Bootstrap as my CSS framework, however i don't want to use it for all my css. I have some other style sheets such as calculator.css but there are certain elements of the css that are being overridden by Bootstrap.

How would i go about keeping Bootstrap as the css framework and then call just my style sheets on certain pages where i don't want to use Bootstrap?

For example i have a page called calculator within a home controller, with a calculator.css file for styling. All i would like to do is call my calculator.css file for that page.

Has anyone dealt with this before, any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure the bootstrap css is loaded *before* your other css.  For example, your application css file might look similar to this afterwards:

```
*= require_self  
*= require bootstrap
*= require myfile
```

Comment: would you mind expanding on this a little please, just explaining what is happening. Im new to rails, thanks

Comment: also have tried this and now the pages that use bootstrap now have no styling at all, its ignoring bootstrap. i installed the bootstrap gem. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the [Rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).  That should help you understand everything you need to know .